# How do I automatically change the camera in a track in Trackmania 2?

Tags: trackmania-2

I'm trying to get the camera to change while excuting a loop.

In previous Trackmania games (such as Nations) you would create a ghost file (the track is now haunted), within the ghost recording you would set a trigger at the beginning of loop, set the camera (to internal), and create a second trigger at the end of the loop to set the camera back to default.

In Trackmania 2 I've created the ghost file and added the triggers, when I replay the ghost file, the camera switches like I expect, however, when I validate the track, the triggers do not fire, and the camera never changes.

What am I missing?